# Ternary operator in Spring PropertySource doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, spring, configuration, configuration-files, ternary-operator

I am using Spring Framework 4.2.5, and am running an executable JAR. What I want to do is configure a @PropertySource on a configuration class that will:

1. Load properties from a file on disk whose path is specified by a system property 'config.file' on the command line, if that system property is present.
2. Load properties from a default properties file on the classpath if the 'config.file' property is not set.

If I were able to use Spring Boot in this instance, this would not be an issue. I can almost get there with:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:default.properties", "${config.file}"})
```

Except that doing it this way requires (as far as I can tell) that **config.file** be specified as 'file:path/to/file' instead of just 'path/to/file', which I would like to avoid if possible. So I turned to the SPEL ternary operator, coming up with something along the lines of:

```
@PropertySource("#{'${config.file}' != '' ? 'file:${config.file}' : 'classpath:default.properties'}")
```

(and some other variations on the theme), but what I end up with is the property source trying to load from one the following depending upon the presence of config.file:

```
'' != '' ? 'file:' : 'classpath:default.properties'
'my.props' != '' ? 'file:my.props' : 'classpath:default.properties'
```

which is the string expanded out but not evaluated. I'm not sure if I'm doing the SPEL or the ternary operator incorrectly correctly (my bet is here), or if the @PropertySource won't evaluate the SPEL fully. Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.

Update:

I also tried using multiple @PropertySource annotations like so:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:default.properties")
@PropertySource(value="${config.file}", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
```

Which seems like an approach that should work, and Spring does indeed try to process the second @PropertySource, but no matter what is specified using "file:path/to/file", "file://path/to/file" or simply "path/to/file", I am informed that the "class path resource [value] cannot be opened because it does not exist". By the examples given in the documentation, it seems like non-classpath resources are permitted, but that's not the behavior I am seeing.

Comment: Don't try to hack the `@PropertySource` for that, use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which adds the additional property source. That way you can simply check if the property is there, use that to construct a `PropertySource` or use the default one.

Comment: I agree that the ternary expression is hackish. I will give the initializer a try.